# Is there an English translation of Parimala of Shri Appaya Diskhita available?

Tags: advaita, translation, commentary, appayya-dikshitar

Is there an English translation of Parimala of Shri Appaya Diskhita available?

Please provide the link for the same.

More about this work (from [here](https://shaivam.org/to-practise/works-of-sri-appaiya-dikshita)):

> 3. Kalpataruparimala :
>
> Bhagavadpada Adi Sri Sankaracharya wrote a classic commentary on the
> Brahmasutras of Badarayans. For this commentary or Bhashya of Sri
> Sankara, a great advaitic teacher, by name Sri Vachaspati Misra wrote
> another commentary called Bhamati. For this work Bhamati, another
> subsequent advaitic teacher by name Amalananda wrote an abstruse and
> difficult commentary called kalpataru. The kalpataru is an extremely
> difficult piece of work, which would require extensive scholarship to
> understand. For this work kalpataru, **Sri Appayya Dikshita wrote an
> extensive and easily understandable detailed commentary called the
> Parimala.**

Comment: Welcome to our site! Hope you don't mind my edit.

Comment: @rickross thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the **parimala has not been translated to English**.

The sanskrit book called [Brahmasutra sankara bhashya](https://www.centreforbrahmavidya.org/acharyas/sri-amalananda/brahmasutra-shankara-bhashya-with-bhamati,-kalpataru-and-parimala.html) edited by N. S. Anantakrishna Sastri and Vasudev Lakshman Sastri Panshikar by Nirnayasagar Press, Bombay, 1917 includes vAcaspati's bhAmatI, amalAnanda's kalpataru and appayya dIkshita's parimala. This is the comprehensive book. The sanskrit of the parimala text [alone is available](https://archive.org/details/VedantaKalpataruParimalaPart12VSS14/page/n5/mode/2up). There is commentary on the kalpatru called Abhogah Kalpataru Vyakhya by Lakṣmīnr̥siṃha and is also available in [sanskrit](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.495737/page/n903/mode/2up).

Kindly note that amalaananda wrote books for both the [subschools of advaita, bhamati and vivarna.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36044/what-are-the-different-sub-schools-of-advaitha), called the [vedanta kalpatru](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.495740) and [sastra darpana](https://archive.org/details/Sastra.Darpana.by.Sri.Amalananda/page/n1/mode/2up), respectively.

If possible, you should read [siddhanta lesha sangraha](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.211961/page/n65/mode/2up) of appayya dikshitar. He integrates the philosophies of both bhamati and vivarna schools. This is available in English, as linked above.

Comment: Excellent answer @GIRIBLR